# Friday's Fujisan Problem

Tags: dominoes

Four Shinto Priests have traveled from their various prefectures in pilgrimage
to the top of Mount Fuji. You must find pathways for them to move up and down
the mountain until they can all achieve the peak. Often, this will require you
to guide them into positions from which they can assist each other. See
[Monday's problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/117426/38) for the full rules, and [Wednesday's problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/117455/38) for more
practice.

Today's problem is even more challenging. Good luck, and post your solution
as an answer with each move labeled for pawn A, B, C, or D, the direction, and
the number of steps. If someone else has posted an answer, see if you can find
one with fewer moves.

[image: Starting position]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Computer Generated Solution

All four priests to the mountain in

> 65 moves.

Step 1:

> 1: B>3    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 3
>    2: B<1    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 2
>    3: B>2    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 4
>    4: B      : Move Priest B to the top of domino 4
>    5: B>5    : Move Priest B to the top of domino 9
>    6: B>3    : Move Priest B to the top of domino 12
>    7: B      : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 12

Step 2:

> 8: D<2    : Move Priest D to the bottom of domino 10
>    9: B<3    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 8
>   10: B<3    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 5
>   11: B      : Move Priest B to the top of domino 5
>   12: B<4    : Move Priest B to the top of domino 1
>   13: B      : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 1
>   14: B>1    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 2
>   15: B>2    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 4
>   16: B      : Move Priest B to the top of domino 4
>   17: B>5    : Move Priest B to the top of domino 9
>   18: D      : Move Priest D to the top of domino 10
>   19: D<1    : Move Priest D to the top of domino 8
>   20: B      : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 9
>   21: D      : Move Priest D to the bottom of domino 8
>   22: B<3    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 5
>   23: B>5    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 11
>   24: B      : Move Priest B to the top of domino 11
>   25: D      : Move Priest D to the top of domino 8
>   26: D>3    : Move Priest D to the top of domino 12

Step 3:

> 27: C<1    : Move Priest C to the top of domino 10
>   28: B      : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 11
>   29: B<3    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 8
>   30: B<3    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 5
>   31: B      : Move Priest B to the top of domino 5
>   32: B<4    : Move Priest B to the top of domino 1
>   33: B      : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 1
>   34: B>1    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 2
>   35: B>2    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 4
>   36: B      : Move Priest B to the top of domino 4
>   37: B>5    : Move Priest B to the top of domino 9
>   38: B      : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 9
>   39: D      : Move Priest D to the bottom of domino 12
>   40: D<3    : Move Priest D to the bottom of domino 8
>   41: C      : Move Priest C to the bottom of domino 10
>   42: C<3    : Move Priest C to the bottom of domino 5
>   43: C      : Move Priest C to the top of domino 5
>   44: B<3    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 5
>   45: C<4    : Move Priest C to the top of domino 1
>   46: C      : Move Priest C to the bottom of domino 1
>   47: C>1    : Move Priest C to the bottom of domino 2
>   48: C>2    : Move Priest C to the bottom of domino 4
>   49: D<3    : Move Priest D to the bottom of domino 3
>   50: B      : Move Priest B to the top of domino 5
>   51: B<4    : Move Priest B to the top of domino 1
>   52: C      : Move Priest C to the top of domino 4
>   53: D      : Move Priest D to the top of domino 3

Step 4:

> 54: A>2    : Move Priest A to the top of domino 5
>   55: A      : Move Priest A to the bottom of domino 5
>   56: B      : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 1
>   57: B>4    : Move Priest B to the bottom of domino 6
>   58: B      : Move Priest B to the top of domino 6
>   59: D      : Move Priest D to the bottom of domino 3
>   60: D<2    : Move Priest D to the bottom of domino 1
>   61: D>4    : Move Priest D to the bottom of domino 6
>   62: C      : Move Priest C to the bottom of domino 4
>   63: C>1    : Move Priest C to the bottom of domino 7
>   64: C      : Move Priest C to the top of domino 7
>   65: A>1    : Move Priest A to the bottom of domino 7

Comment: Thanks for solving all three puzzles this week! 

Answer (score 1):

Notes:

> A needs 3 help to do A>2
>  B needs 0 help to do B>3
>  C needs 2 help to do C<1
>  D needs 1 help to do D<2
>  So the order is B, D, C, A.

Step 1:

> B>3 B<1 B>2 B B>5 B>3 B (7 moves, unlocks D)
>  [image]

Step 2:

> D<2 B<3 B<3 B B<4 B B>1 B>2 B B>5 D D<1 D B B<3 B>5 B D D>3 (19 moves, unlocks C)
>  [image]

Step 3:

> C<1 C D D<3 D<3 D D<4 D D>1 D>2 D D>5 C B<1 B D C C<3 C C<4 C C>1 C>2 D<3 B<3 D<1 D B C (29 moves, unlocks A)
>  [image]

Step 4:

> A>2 D D>4 A C B B>1 B B<1 C>1 C A>1 (12 moves, all to peak)
>  [image]

Total: 67 moves

Moving the first priest from the right side to the left side requires intricate maneuver, exemplified in Step 2 and Step 3.

Comment: I'm holding off on posting the computer-generated solution until Sunday, but I'll confirm that Steps 1 and 2 of this solution are optimal.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised Step 4 is not optimal. Probably the starting point is different, I suppose? There are 4 possible starting points for Step 4.

Comment: Indeed. In fact, the solution I have takes one move *longer* to do step 4, but makes up for it with a shorter step 3, for a (very slightly) shorter overall solution.

Comment: I see. Yea, I didn't consider different Step 3 that led to longer Step 4, haha

Comment: Thanks for solving all three puzzles this week! 